# File permissions/ownership on network share in MSYS2 vs Cygwin?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, file-permissions, msys2

I work on Windows 10, with both MSYS2 and Cygwin installed.

For the most part I work with MSYS2 (or rather, MINGW64 shell in this case), and I generally do not have a problem accessing files on a network share with whatever program that runs under MINGW64.

When I check the permissions from MINGW64, I get e.g.:

```
user@PC MINGW64 //MYSERVER/myshare/test
$ ls -la
total 38M
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None    0 Dec  3 15:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 user None    0 Nov 28 08:36 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user None 7.4M Dec  3 13:20 test_one.png
....
```

However, if I try the same from the Cygwin shell, I get this:

```
user@PC //MYSERVER/myshare/test
$ ls -la
total 38900
drwxrwx---+ 1 Unknown+User Unix_Group+65534       0 Dec  3 15:28 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 Unknown+User Unix_Group+65534       0 Nov 28 08:36 ..
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Unknown+User Unix_Group+65534 7666914 Dec  3 13:20 test_one.png
...
```

Clearly, Cygwin does not see `user` as the owner of this file, but instead, it sees `Unknown+User` as the owner.

Correspondingly, if I want to open this file in, say, `feh`, I get:

```
feh WARNING: test_one.png - No read access
```

Can I somehow setup Cygwin, so it sees the same ownership/permission of a file on a Windows networks share, the same as MINGW64 sees it?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, fixed this, thanks to this blog post: https://salonen.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/fixing-file-permissions-on-network-shares-in-cygwin/

Basically, my `/etc/fstab` in Cygwin was just this:

```
# /etc/fstab
#
#    This file is read once by the first process in a Cygwin process tree.
#    To pick up changes, restart all Cygwin processes.  For a description
#    see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

# This is default anyway:
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

I simply added `,noacl` to the last (and only uncommented) line, like this:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0
```

... then closed the Cygwin terminal, opened it again, `cd` to `//MYSERVER/myshare/test` - and now, all files appear to be owned by user+group `user None`, just as in the MSYS2 case, and they open fine.

Another useful command in Cygwin I found (via https://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/lZOZG8Ut/network-drive-file-permissions-permission-denied) is this one (here inspecting the directory `//MYSERVER/myshare/test`):

```
$ /usr/lib/csih/getVolInfo .
Device Type        : 7
Characteristics    : 10
Volume Name        : <myshare>
Serial Number      : 193090813
Max Filenamelength : 255
Filesystemname     : <NTFS>
Flags              : 5002f
  FILE_CASE_SENSITIVE_SEARCH  : TRUE
  FILE_CASE_PRESERVED_NAMES   : TRUE
  FILE_UNICODE_ON_DISK        : TRUE
  FILE_PERSISTENT_ACLS        : TRUE
  FILE_FILE_COMPRESSION       : FALSE
  FILE_VOLUME_QUOTAS          : TRUE
  FILE_SUPPORTS_SPARSE_FILES  : FALSE
  FILE_SUPPORTS_REPARSE_POINTS: FALSE
  FILE_SUPPORTS_REMOTE_STORAGE: FALSE
  FILE_VOLUME_IS_COMPRESSED   : FALSE
  FILE_SUPPORTS_OBJECT_IDS    : TRUE
  FILE_SUPPORTS_ENCRYPTION    : FALSE
  FILE_NAMED_STREAMS          : TRUE
  FILE_READ_ONLY_VOLUME       : FALSE
  FILE_SEQUENTIAL_WRITE_ONCE  : FALSE
  FILE_SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS  : FALSE
```

Comment: The easy way will be to copy the `/etc/fstab` file from msys2 to cygwin. In msys2, that file already has `noacl` option and no `cygdrive` prefix. So, any shell script accessing Windows drive will work in both msys2 and cygwin.